# Average distance between two outputs of a probability density function with real numbers as output?

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a 1-dimensional PDF with real numbers as output I need to find the average of distances $|a-b|$ between two outputs of such PDF. What I know is that the integral of the PDF must be 1 from -infinity to +infinity, and I somehow need to use an integral to sum up all the distances taking into account the probabilities of the outputs, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you compute the average difference between the numbers shown when you roll two dice?

Comment: What if you have two unfair coins: each comes up heads 3/4 of the time. Call the difference "1" if one is heads, the other is tails, and the difference zero otherwise. Can you compute the average difference in *that* situation?

Comment: The average distance based on the PDF $f$ is $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|x-y|\,f(x)f(y)\,dxdy$$

Comment: @JohnHughes ?? The term "PDF" refers to continuous random variables. The results of coins and dice are discrete.

Comment: I was aware of that, Did. But if OP cannot answer the discrete question, the chances are very good that OP cannot answer the continuous one either; on the other hand, if the discrete question is easy, then the generalization to the continuous case (aside from questions of integrability) is relatively easy. Of course, it's even easier now that you've disclosed it, and OP can feel free to do the computation without ever understanding anything about the question at all. Forgive me for asking the kinds of leading questions from which I find students often learn.

Comment: @Did Can it be generalized to two distributions?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $